# Scala Play 2.0: Is it possible to use case classes in "routes"

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0, case-class

My "routes" file looks something like:

```
# Routes
GET     /         controllers.Application.action(p1 ?= 1, p2 ?= 2, p3 ?= "", p4 ?= "")
```

I want to have something like:

```
case class FilterGroup(p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: String, p4: String) // defined in controllers
```

---

```
# Routes
GET     /         controllers.Application.action(fg ?= FilterGroup(1, 2, "", ""))
```

The advantages is that it will give more extensibility in .scala.html when you need to add or remove some parameters.

Is that possible to implement?

Comment: Making `FilterGroup` a [PathBindable](http://julien.richard-foy.fr/blog/2012/04/09/how-to-implement-a-custom-pathbindable-with-play-2/) might be a possible approach, but I'm not sure you can currently bind multiple parameters at once.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at QueryStringBindable and PathBindable traits. Try to implement implicit binders for your case classes ([here is example](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Binders.scala)), and then you need to set in project settings in your build.sbt route import with packages in which kept your case classes and binders:

```
  routesImport ++= Seq("foo", "bar")
```

Comment: This seems like a lot of code for not a lot of benefit. :(